# looping through multiple arrays in php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to insert three protocols in a table "service_providers" under "protocol" field and three plateforms in the same table under "plateform" field, when i click on submit button three records should be inserted in "service_providers" table.

admin/protocol" method="post">
                     
                            Protocols
                            

                              
                               
                                
                            
                          


                          
                            Plateform

this is the action code

```
 <?php 

             $service_id  = $this->db->insert_id();

                      $protocols = $this->input->post('protocol');
                      $plateform     = $this->input->post('plateform');
                        foreach($protocols as $protocol){
                              foreach($protocols as $protocol){
                                    $data= array(
                                        'protocols' => $protocol,
                                        'country'   => $country
                                        );  

                                $this->db->insert('service_providers',$data);
                              }
                        }
```

when i code like that six records insert , which is wrong

```
 <?php 

                  $protocols = $this->input->post('protocol');
                  $plateform     = $this->input->post('plateform');
                    foreach($protocols as $protocol){
                          foreach($plateforms as $plateform){
                                $data= array(
                                    'protocols' => $protocol,
                                    'plateform' => $plateform
                                    );  


                          }
                $this->db->insert('service_providers',$data);
                    }


?>
```

when i code like that three records insert , which is right but inner foreach loop's values do not insert how to tackle this i want like that in database

```
id       protocol      plateform     service_id 
1      PPTP      Windows      100
2     OpenVPN    Andriod      100
3     LPTP       iOS           100
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @aqsa jamil Did you check my answer? or found solution by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your action :
This will work only if protocol and plateform having number of parameters.

```
$protocols = $this->input->post('protocol');
$plateform     = $this->input->post('plateform');
$k =0;

foreach($protocols as $protocol){

        $data= array(
        'protocols' => $protocol,
        'plateform' => $plateform[$k]
        );  
        $this->db->insert('service_providers',$data);
        $k++;
}
```